# Empty sudoku and NP-completeness

Tags: np-hardness, optimization

My question is straightforward: Is an empty sudoku grid (not partially completed) still NP-complete?

Comment: No (unless $P=NP$). You can always fill a blank sudoku in polynomial time. You can read about the algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms#Blank_Sudoku_grids)

Comment: There is a minor technicality here. To specify an empty sudoku grid all we need to specify is the size of the puzzle. A sudoku puzzle is parameterized by $$n$$ and the size itself is a $$n^2 \times n^2$$ grid. However, specifying $$n$$ takes only $$\log n$$ bits while the solutions requires writing down $$n^2 \times n^2$$ numbers.

Comment: NP is a class of decision problems. Since the empty grid is always solvable, the algorithm is "ignore the input and answer YES", which is constant-time irrespective of whether the input is given in unary, binary, or any other way.

Comment: An empty grid is a unary language – there's only one for each $n$ – so it cannot be NP-complete by Mahaney's theorem (unless P=NP).